# Regular expression for comma separated text but not surround with digits

Tags: java, regex

I need to split the text with comma separated but not with surround digit like below
Text is `LOCAL_GUA_CONTRACT_AMT NUMBER(22,3) , LOCAL_GUA_CONTRACT_AMT NUMBER(22,3)`
and output is `LOCAL_GUA_CONTRACT_AMT NUMBER(22,3)`
                      `LOCAL_GUA_CONTRACT_AMT NUMBER(22,3)`

Comment: And what is your code?

Comment: in java, the string is given, previously i have applied text.split(",");
but its not right solution

Comment: If there are spaces surrounding the comma you want to split at, then split("\\s+,\\s+")

Comment: If there are always the whitespaces around the comma you want to split on, you could simply use that?

Comment: @NomadMaker dear i have not mentioned about white spaces surround comma, no its common sense we will handle in regular expression, you can check the ans below.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex: (?<=[^0-9]),(?=[^0-9])

```
text.split("(?<=[^0-9]),(?=[^0-9])")
```

it will split with comma as a separator but never if numbers are next to it. But it will leave whitespaces as they were

And if you want whitespaces to be deleted also, use this

```
(?<=[^0-9])\s*,\s*(?=[^0-9])
```